# ReactJS: GET http://localhost:8080/contact 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

Trying to use BrowserRouter in my app, not sure where I am going wrong, but I think it might have to do with my webpack. Ultimately, I can have any of the components served when path='/' on the first render.
Once I try to hit a different path, say path='/contact' I get a 404 error.

Webpack.config.js -

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: { app: './src/App.jsx' },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks:{
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all',
        },
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

App.jsx -

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// import Page from './Page.jsx';
import About from './About.jsx';
import Contact from './Contact.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

server.js -

```
let express = require('express');

let app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

And my file structure is as follows

```
- Root Directory
package.json
webpack.config.js
.gitignore
.env
 -> public
  |-> app.bundle.js
  |-> app.bundle.js.map
  |-> App.js
  |-> index.html
  |-> vendor.bundle.js
  |-> vendor.bundle.js.map
 -> server
  |-> server.js
 -> src
  |-> .babelrc
  |-> About.jsx
  |-> App.jsx
  |-> Contact.jsx
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used express, but I'm not seeing a fallback route that serves your index.html for "/contact" route. If you add a `Link` from `react-router-dom` to navigate to "/contact" with out a redirect (i.e. Go to the base route, click a link get taken to "/contact") this would work as it does not hit the server, but refreshing on the "/contact" page would cause the 404 again. TLDR: You have not told express to serve the index.html page when going to "/contact"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import Switch for switching routes

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then Modify the return function like following and add 'exact' to your route definition.

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={About} exact/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} exact/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

This will render the desired component on `/contact` route

Comment: Thank you for the contribution but this did not work. I believe Jacob Smit may be correct in saying that I have not told express to serve the index.html page when going to "/contacts", although I still have to implement this solution.

Comment: So I had a friend notify me that indeed Jacob Smit was right about my error and that a simple fix is to implement  `app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public", "index.html"));
}); ` in my server.js file.